# Session Timer [PHP]

Tags: php, session

I currently have a timer set on a session to end in 30 minutes after the session has started.

```
$now = time();
if($now > $_SESSION['expire']){
session_destroy();
}
```

And $_SESSION['expire'] is set by this:

```
$_SESSION['start'] = time(); // taking now logged in time 
$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60) ;
```

I want to place a countdown on the site to see how long is left in the session.
So that it would countdown from 30 mins.

How would I go about doing this?

Regards,
Timmy

Comment: Is your question about building the countdown or how to calculate how much time is left in the session?

Comment: I can build the countdown, I just want to calculate the time left :)

Comment: It's nothing more than substracting `$now` from your expiration time.

Comment: What I mean is to output it in minutes xD

Comment: Use the `date`function: http://de2.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php Otherwise your result when substracting the both timestamps gives a value measured in seconds. Devide it by 60 and you have it in minutes.

Comment: So how would I for example get 29.9833333333 into a time format using the `date` function? I'm not very familiar with using date.

Comment: I'm sorry, `date` is for converting timestamps only. Use `number_format`, `sprintf` or something similar to format a string or a number.

Comment: Ok, so although all that worked great, for some reason I can't get a plain text timer that work properly.